# ReactJS get XMLHttpRequest not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to get XML-Data from an XML-file and want to save certain node values in a list. This is how I tried to do it:

```
import React from "react";

class EditFiles extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.loadXML = this.loadXML.bind(this);
    }

    loadXML = () => {

        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

                var xmlDoc = this.responseXML;
                var y = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("newFile");

                for(var i=0; i<y.length; i++) {

                    var NameArray = [y[i].getElementsByTagName("FileName")[0]];
                }

                const nameList = NameArray.map(name => 
                    <li>{name}</li>
                );
            }
        };

        xhttp.open("GET", "./FilenameList.xml", true);
        xhttp.send();

    }

    render() {
        return(
            <ul>{nameList}</ul>
        );
    }
}
```

First of all, I don't know if it can even be done this way. I did find similar questions, however, the code in the answers was not explained very well and I don't want to just copy and paste some code without understanding it (also, even if I wanted to do that, I probably couldn't, since I wouldn't know what represents what.
The error I'm getting with this code is that `nameList` is not defined in the render function. I know that it would have to be a global function, but I do not know how to do that.

I also read this post: https://medium.com/@catquarks/making-ajax-requests-with-react-48be0285d396 and wanted to do it like in the example. But I don't quite understand it, for example, how would I get the value of certain tags?

Anyway, to sum up my goal for this question: Can I use an XMLHttpRequest the way I did and what mistakes did I make exactly?

I hope this isn't all over the place. If you need further information/explanation please let me know.

Quick Edit: the XML-file looks kinda like this:

```
<Files>
    <newFile>
        <FileName>file1</FileName>
    </newFile>
    <newFile>
        <FileName>file2</FileName>
    </newFile>
</Files>
```

What I would also like to note, is that the xml-file is created dynamically, therefore it's not predictable how many `newFile` nodes there are going to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tell React how and when to execute the code in your `loadXML` function. Binding it like you did in the constructor is useless here, as `bind` simply changes the `this` keyword for the `loadXML` function. And actually, React comes with a set of functions you should use instead, as `loadXML`'s purpose is to fetch data from an external source.

In your case, `componentDidMount` is the right place to execute the code instructions of `loadXML`.

A best practice is to :

- set your initial `state` in the `contructor()` function
- load external data (what you do with `XMLHttpRequest` in the `componentDidMount()` function

More generally, the [React Component Lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle) is a very insightful source to understand the various functions that are executed when displaying and updating a React component. You may find [this example](http://mediatemple.net/blog/tips/loading-and-using-external-data-in-react/) useful too.

One your data has been loaded, then update the `state` of your component with the data you obtain. Updating the `state` (or `props`) of a React component automatically triggers its `render()` function and display your changes.

Then, in the `render()` function, just return the DOM elements (or React components) to display based on the component's state variable. In the following example, we download JSON data (posts) from a URL using `XMLHttpRequest` and return the `title` of each post. We tell `render()` to check the length of the `posts` array in order to know if we have posts to display.

You can run the code snippet directly, data is JSON based (not XML), but I'm sure you can adapt it to your case.

```js
class EditFiles extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          posts: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      var self = this;
      
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(e){
        console.log(this);
        if (xhttp.readyState === 4 && xhttp.status === 200){
          console.log("ok, response :", this.response);
          self.setState({
            posts: JSON.parse(this.response)
          });
        }
      }
      xhttp.open("get", "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", true);
      xhttp.send();
    }

    render() {
      let postsLoaded = this.state.posts.length > 0;
      return(
        postsLoaded ?
          <ul>
          {
            this.state.posts.map(
              post => {
                return <li>{ post.title }</li>;
              })
          }
          </ul>
          :
          <div>Loading...</div>
      );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <EditFiles />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I just have a quick question, I just tried out this code with a json file on the server I am using. The file is in the same director so I link to it this way : "./somefile.json", however, I received this error: `Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0` so I guess i didn't choose the right path or something, do you know how to link to it properly? You too have a great day!

Comment: Let's discuss that in a chat room https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/161272/room-for-asj-and-philippe?tab=access ok for you ?